# Meson custom_target output directory for generated sources

Tags: c++, soap, meson-build

I have a directory (project) structure like this:

```
main_project_dir (main meson.build file)
    project_A (meson.build)
    project_B (meson.build)
```

In directory `project_A` meson.build file uses a source file generator, like this:

```
gen_empty_soap_src = custom_target('empty_soap_src',
    input : 'empty.gsoap',
    output : ['soapC.cpp', 'soapH.h', 'soapStub.h', 'soap.nsmap'],
    depend_files : soap_gen_depend_files,
    command : [soap_compiler, '-n', '-I', '.', '@INPUT@'])

gen_base_soap_src = custom_target('base_soap_src',
    input : 'AbstractAgentAPI.gsoap',
    output : [
        ... a list of output files ...
    ],
    depend_files : soap_gen_depend_files,
    command : [soap_compiler, '-n', '-I', '.',
                '-I' + join_paths(meson.current_source_dir(), soap_src_dir, 'import'),
                '-I' + join_paths(meson.current_source_dir(), soap_src_dir),
                '@INPUT@'])
```

The generated files suppose to be under `project_A` directory when generated. That means that the directory structure should be preserved during the build the files should go under `build/project_A` directory. But they are generated in `build` directory.

I was looking into the documentation, and I already found somewhere that for **generators** the output directory is the meson build directory by default.

How can I make the generated files to go in a certain directory, `build/project_A` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like that the best practice is to specify the output directory for generated files. In my case I use `-d` parameter.

To specify this dir as the output dir in Meson, `@OUTDIR@` should be used.
So my code now looks like this:

```
gen_empty_soap_src = custom_target('empty_soap_src',
    input : 'empty.gsoap',
    output : ['soapC.cpp', 'soapH.h', 'soapStub.h', 'soap.nsmap'],
    depend_files : soap_gen_depend_files,
    command : [soap_compiler, '-n', '-d', '@OUTDIR@', '-I', '.', '@INPUT@'])

gen_base_soap_src = custom_target('base_soap_src',
    input : 'AbstractAgentAPI.gsoap',
    output : [
        ... a list of output files ...
    ],
    depend_files : soap_gen_depend_files,
    command : [soap_compiler, '-n',
                '-d', '@OUTDIR@',
                '-I', '.',
                '-I' + join_paths(meson.current_source_dir(), soap_src_dir, 'import'),
                '-I' + join_paths(meson.current_source_dir(), soap_src_dir),
                '@INPUT@'])
```

A note from the Meson author:

> Don't use current_build_dir(). Use @OUTDIR@ instead. In general if you
>   find you are manually building paths that point inside the build or
>   source trees, you are probably doing something wrong.
>
> Because @OUTDIR@ is guaranteed to work. Different backends do things
>   differently and might place files in different places. It is also
>   shorter and self-documenting.